# Slow performance UICollectionView with async image downloading

Tags: performance, afnetworking, uicollectionview, sdwebimage

I'm getting slow performance when using third party frameworks for async images download.
I've tried the `AFNetworking` and `SDWebImage`, the scrolling of the `UICollectionView` becomes very slow.

I've tried the following:

```
-(void)setImageForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)path withUrl:(NSURL*)url{
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
AFImageRequestOperation *operation;
operation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(UIImage *image) {
    CollectionCellPreview *cell = (CollectionCellPreview *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:path];
    cell.myImageView.image = image;
}];
[operation start];
```

}

As also:

```
[cell.imageLocation setImageWithURL:url];
```

Am I missing something important by using this frameworks? It seems very useful and powerful and I don't understand why it behaves this way.

Comment: Do you mean the images download slowly?  Or you have choppy scrolling in your collection view?

Comment: I have choppy scrolling in the UICollectionView, I've noticed that its is slower on the simulator.

Comment: I am using UICollectionView with SDWebImage. I don't have the slow scrolling issue. The issue might come from somewhere else.

Answer (score 4):

Use Xcode's Time Profiler in Build -> Profile to see what's causing the lag. It's almost certainly in some code you've written, although I have seen auto layout cause some issues too, especially if your views are complex.

Time Profiler tutorial here, although it's for an older version: http://blancer.com/tutorials/flex/78335/apple-profiling-tools-shark-is-out-instruments-is-in/

Analysis of Auto-Layout performance here: http://pilky.me/view/36